# Template missing error when trying to set up mailer - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to send an email upon creation of an object. Right now I have a notifier class in my mailer, I have a method called tasklist_confirmation then I have a view folder called notifier and a file called tasklist_confirmation.html.erb But when I try to create the object from the browser I get this error `Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/intern/Desktop/Play/Lockdown/app/views" * "/Users/intern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"`

I'll show my code for anything I may be missing.

### Notifier.rb

```
class Notifier < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => 'cam@collectiveidea.com'

  def tasklist_confirmation(user)
    @user = user

    mail to: @user.email,
         subject: 'Thanks for creating a tasklist'
  end
end
```

### View

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>thanks for creating a tasklist, <%= @user.name %>!</h1>
    <p>You are about to get stuff done!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have an *app/mailers/application_mailer.html.erb* file - by default it requests *layout/mailer* which doesn't exist. Either remove that file or add *layout false* in your *notifier.rb* file.